# Data Not ready to read from Stream

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to send "Hello" from Server to Client on getting connected... Server side program is running properly but Client side code is having a problem that "Data is not ready to read"

These are my codes... Please Help...

Server Side :

```
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class ServerSide
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
{   
       try
       {    
           ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8888);
       System.out.println("Waiting...");    
           Socket server=ss.accept();
           PrintStream ps= new PrintStream(server.getOutputStream());
           ps.print("Hello...");
           ps.flush();
       System.out.println("Data Sent...");

       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
         System.out.println("Error : " + e.toString());
       }
   }
    }
```

Client Side :

```
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;

    public class ClientSide 
    {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
       {
       String str= new String();
           Socket client=new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),8888);
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
               if(br.ready())
               {
                    str=br.readLine();
                System.out.println(str);
               }
           else
               {
                    System.out.println("Data not ready to read from Stream");
               }
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
        System.out.println("Error : " + e.toString());
       }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're currently failing if the `BufferedReader` hasn't got any data *immediately* after it's created. Why would you expect it to have? Personally I very rarely find `ready()` and `available()` to be useful methods - I suggest you just call `readLine` and block until there *is* data available.

As noted in comments, if you're trying to *read* lines from the client, you need to *write* lines on the server - so consider using `println` instead of `print`. (I'm personally not a fan of `PrintStream` to start with, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: @Sarjit Delivala: If you do a readLine(), don't forget to do a println() instead of print() on the server side

Comment: @RenéLink: Well it will close the socket as it exists, and then the client will see the end of the stream... Have edited the answer to mention this point though.

Comment: Thank you Jon Skeet... :) Data is now transmitted but after transmission Connection Reset Error is coming... What can be the reason for that? And what should I use instead of PrintStream?

Comment: @SarjitDelivala: Well I'd use `OutputStreamWriter` with a specific encoding. It's not clear where you're getting the other exception, but bear in mind that you're not *closing* the socket on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
String in = null;
while ((in = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // This will loop until EOF and in will hold the last read line
}
```